# Lifetime Confusion for iterator

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am new to Rust and currently have been following [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-iter-mut.html) examples. Before section `IterMut` everything makes sense to me. Yet when implementing `IterMut`(in a differrnt way from the tutorial), I got totally confused by lifetime mechanism in Rust. Here is the case, first I'd just define the stack to be implemented:

```rust
pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}
```

Ok then when I try to implement iterator in the following way:

```rust
pub struct IterMut<'a, T>{
    this: &'a mut Link<T>
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut<T> {
        IterMut {
            this: &mut self.head
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T>{
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(node) = self.this {
            Some(&mut node.elem)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

It won't compile, the result says:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T>{
    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
        if let Some(node) = self.this {
            Some(&mut node.elem)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

Originally, I implement function `next` in this way, using `as_mut` and `map`:

```rust
// function body in the fn next
self.this.as_mut().map(|node|{
    self.this = &mut node.next;
    &mut node.elem
})
```

This also triggers compilation error (incompatible lifetime).

Therefore I wonder what is going on here, shouldn't `self` in `fn next` have the same lifetime as `IterMut` ('a)? And is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: I think the reason this is different is because shared references (`&`) are `Copy` while exclusive references (`&mut`) are not. So to use the exclusive reference there must be a guarantee that you can't obtain the same mutable reference again. (Note that as written, if you call `next()` twice you'll get the same mutable reference back, which would be a problem -- that's why the lifetime of the return value must be bound to the lifetime of `&mut self` in this particular implementation.)

Comment: Thanks! I think I forgot to update `self.this` in the code, right before returning `Some(&mut )`, like this: `self.this = &mut node.next;`. Does that mean even if I update `self.this` (so I won't get exactly the same `&node.elem` since the node is different in two `next` call), the returned `&node.elem` might outlive `&mut self` then it would be possible for me to get two mutable references, since the returned value has lifetime 'a? But in this case, which variable will be referenced twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principal problem lies in trying to take a reference to the whole `head`. While that reference lives, you can't hand out mutable references to anything inside it. You only need access to the `Node` that's inside `head`, though. So first, we refactor `IterMut` to only keep a reference into any given `Node`:

```rust
pub struct IterMut<'a, T>{
    this: Option<&'a mut Node<T>>
}
```

Now, to get that out of the `head` we use the convenience method `as_deref_mut()` that `Option` provides. It just gives us a mutable reference to whatever was inside it (if anything):

```rust
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut<'_, T> {
        IterMut {
            this: self.head.as_deref_mut(),
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `'a` is only tied to that `Node` and we can do what we want with it, like `take`ing it:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T>{
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(node) = self.this.take() {
            self.this = node.next.as_deref_mut();
            Some(&mut node.elem)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

And we can simplify that with a simple `map` call:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T>{
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.this.take().map(|node| {
            self.this = node.next.as_deref_mut();
            &mut node.elem
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought "having multiple mutable references is forbidden" meant I could not have two references pointing to exactly the same variable but I could make reference to the inner field of the variable even when I had a mut reference to the whole var. I guess it would be hard for me to refactor my code in the original way and make it work... And yes, your answer is exactly the implementation of the tutorial, with more explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. simple codes to reproduce the error msg

Construct a function with `&self` or `&mut self` as input and `&'a SOMETHING` as return value, it's not an iterator but have the same effect.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    r_m_s: &'a mut String, // non-Copy
    r_i_s: &'a String, // Copy
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  fn test_return_ref_field(&self) -> &'a String {
    self.r_i_s // Copy, no lifetime problem
  }
  
  fn test_return_ref_mut_field(&mut self) -> &'a mut String {
    //self.r_m_s
    todo!()
  }
}

fn main() {
}
```

`fn test_return_ref_field` is Ok since immutable reference is `Copy` type.

To reproduce the error msg, change `test_return_ref_mut_field` method to return `self.r_m_s`

```rust
fn test_return_ref_mut_field(&mut self) -> &'a mut String {
    self.r_m_s
}
```

And the error msg looks like:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> tt.rs:34:6
   |
26 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
31 |   fn test_return_ref_mut_field(&mut self) -> &'a mut String {
   |                                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
34 |      self.r_m_s
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

error: aborting due to 1 previous error
```

According to error msg, the lifetime of `self.r_m_s` is same as input argument `&mut self`' and no doubt shorter than `'a`.

Because `self.r_m_s` is non-Copy type, and it also can not be partially moved out when behind a reference (the input argument `&mut self`), so its lifetime is as same as `&mut self`.

How about if `self.r_m_s` is a compound type such as `&'a mut Option<String>`, for example:

```
let Some(ref mut v) = self.r_m_s else {
   todo!()
};
v
```

The type of `v` is `&mut String`, and seems nothing related to `self.r_m_s`, but its inferred lifetime is same as `self.r_m_s`, we will encounter the same error. And this is the same situation as `fn next` of the question.

Let's verify it using below example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct F<'a> {
    r: &'a mut Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = "option string".to_string();
    let mut o_str = Some(s);

    let mut f = F {
        r: &mut o_str,
    };

    // create a mutable reference, same as `&mut self`
    let as_mut_ref_self = &mut f;

    let Some(v) = as_mut_ref_self.r else {
       return; 
    };

    v.push_str(" changed by v");

    // create a imutable reference
    // to end the lifetime of as_mut_ref_self
    let as_ref_self = &f;

    // !!! let's check how about the lifetime of v ?
    // !!! uncomment below line will cause error,
    // !!! now we know:
    // !!! the lifetime of v is tied to the as_mut_ref_self
    // println!("{:?}", v);

    println!("{:?}", as_ref_self);
}
```

### 2. unsafe fix

Now the problem is lifetime of return value is not equal to or longer than required lifetime `'a`. Since we know `&mut String` should be valid within lifetime `'a`, **Let's try to cut its ties with the lifetime of `&mut self` directly**.

##### 2.1 one try

Change `test_return_ref_mut_field` method as below:

```rust
fn test_return_ref_mut_field(&mut self) -> &'a mut String { 
    let t: &'static mut String = unsafe {&mut *(self.r_m_s as *mut String)};
    t
}
```

Above codes convert `&mut` to `*mut` raw pointer then convert the raw pointer back.

Although it looks like a local variable `t` created temporarily and returned, but raw pointer have a `'static` life time, it is longer than `'a` obviously.

For your code, you can try this `unsafe` way to convert `&mut node.elem` in `Some(&mut node.elem)`.

**Note: this unsafe fix will have `multiple mut reference` issue, please try below example: **

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    r_m_s: &'a mut String, // non-Copy type
    r_i_s: &'a String, // Copy type
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn test_return_ref_field(&self) -> &'a String {
        self.r_i_s
    }
  
    fn test_return_ref_mut_field(&mut self) -> &'a mut String {
        let t:&'static mut String = unsafe {&mut *(self.r_m_s as *mut String)};
        t
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mut_string = "mut string".to_string();
    let string = "imutable string".to_string();

    let mut f = Foo {
        r_m_s: &mut mut_string,
        r_i_s: &string,
    };

    let ref_mut_1 = f.test_return_ref_mut_field();
    let ref_mut_2 = f.test_return_ref_mut_field();
    let ref_mut_3 = f.test_return_ref_mut_field();

    ref_mut_1.push_str(" by ref_mut_1");
    ref_mut_2.push_str(" by ref_mut_2");
    ref_mut_3.push_str(" by ref_mut_3");
    
    println!("{:#?}", f);

    println!("ref_mut_1: {}\nref_mut_2: {}\nref_mut_3: {}", 
        ref_mut_1, ref_mut_2, ref_mut_3);
    
    println!("{:#?}", f);
}
```

But for `IterMut`, since each time `next` called, `self.this` will be updated to point to `next` node until it reach `None`. there is no chance to mutable reference to same value twice.

##### 2.2 another try

For your codes, you can also change `IterMut` structure to:

```
pub struct IterMut<'a, T>{
    this: *mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

But it will result to an error that `'a not used`, use a phantomdata to hold it:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
pub struct IterMut<'a, T>{
    this: *mut Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}
```

`fn iter_mut` should change to:

```
this: &mut self.head as *mut _,
```

and use it in `fn next` as:

```
let t = unsafe{ &mut *self.p }
```

##### 2.3 use `Option<&'a mut T>` instead of `&'a mut T`

This solution already mentioned in other answers.

`Option` has a convenient `take` method, it is a magic function implement with unsafe codes carefully and you can treat it as a official workaround for some common tasks can not be done under safe mode.

Have a look at below example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]

struct F<'a> {
    r: Option<&'a mut String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s: String = "ssssss".to_string();
    let o_str: Option<&mut String> = Some(&mut s);

    // create a structure holder mutable reference to Option<String>
    let mut f: F<'_> = F {
        r: o_str,
    };

        
    // create a mutable reference
    let as_mut_ref_self = &mut f;
    
    // take the value of f.r by f,
    // and f.r will be replaced by None,
    let take = f.r.take();

    // v is &mut String
    let Some(v) = take else {
        return;
    };

    // to end the lifetime of as_mut_ref_self
    let as_ref_self = &f;

    // mutable reference droped already, 
    // now let's verify v is still valid.
    println!("{}", v);
}
```